# Module parse failed: Unexpected token React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

i tried to setup a new Project with webpack, react and Typescript. Its not working.
Webpack is giving me this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 17:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. 
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

   ERROR
    |
    | ReactDOM.render(
    >   <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
    |   <Router history={history}>
    |       <App />
     @ ./src/index.tsx 2:0-36 6:17-24 7:15-29
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
    
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    
const config = {
    mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.tsx',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Production',
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'style-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
};

if (isProd) {
    config.optimization = {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserWebpackPlugin(),
        ],
    };
} else {
    config.devServer = {
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        overlay: true,
    };
}
    
module.exports = config;
```

package.json:

```json
{      
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "webpack --watch",
        "start": "webpack serve --open",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
        "@types/react-datepicker": "^3.1.8",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
        "@types/yup": "^0.29.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
        "eslint": "^7.29.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "serve": "^12.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.3",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.3.4",
        "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
        "webpack": "^5.40.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
        "yup": "^0.32.9"
    }
}
```

Index.tsx:

```tsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './app/layout/styles.css'
import App from './app/layout/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import {store, StoreContext } from './app/stores/store';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import { Router} from "react-router-dom";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
    
    
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
    
ReactDOM.render(
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </StoreContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
    
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: What is the path to your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: output: {
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

Comment: I mean where does your `webpack.config.js` file reside in your file structure. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: client-app/`webpack.config.js`

client-app/src/`index.tsx`

Comment: What is in your babel (`.babelrc.*` or `babel.config.*`) configuration file? Also quite strange loader selection (`style-loader`) for `.tsx` files.

Comment: {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}